# How can my buttons be visible after adding a new code?

Tags: java, android, webview

my code works well, with 2 buttons ("home" and "chiudi") at the bottom, but I wanted to add more code to my webview app, and this new code hides my buttons.

This is the new code I want to add:

...

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wView, String url)
           {

            if (url.startsWith("mailto:") || url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("geo:") || 
            url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                           Uri.parse(url));

                startActivity(intent);

                return true; 

            } else if (url.startsWith("whatsapp:")) {

                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

                startActivity(sendIntent);

                return true;

             } else if (url.startsWith("spotify:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(
                              "spotify:album:0sNOF9WDwhWunNAHPD3Baj"));
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REFERRER,
                Uri.parse("android-app://" + context.getPackageName()));

                startActivity(intent);

                return true;

             }

             return false;
           }
       });
```

...

And this is my code:

for activity.main.xml:

...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </WebView>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="183dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="191dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="171dp"
        android:layout_x="207dp"
        android:layout_y="629dp"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:onClick="clickexit"
        android:text="Chiudi"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/swipe">

    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="183dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_x="207dp"
        android:layout_y="629dp"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:onClick="gohome"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#0000ff"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </TextView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

...

For MainActivity.java:

...

```
package it...........;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String ONESIGNAL_APP_ID = "a..............";

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private WebView webView;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
        textView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setText("sto caricando");
            }
        }, 500); // delay of 2 seconds before setting a text to textView

        textView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, 2000);


        // Enable verbose OneSignal logging to debug issues if needed.
        OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE);

        // OneSignal Initialization
        OneSignal.initWithContext(this);
        OneSignal.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://d...app");


        //per fare il refresh

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipe);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        webView.reload();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }

        });
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark),
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark),
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark),
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));

    }
        public void gohome(View v)
    {
        webView.loadUrl("https://...app");


    }
    public void clickexit(View v)
    {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(1);

      }
      public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
       }
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
      }


}
```

...

When I add the first code, my buttons disappear.

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Roberto

Answer (score 0):

Your alignment of views is not correct and In `ConstraintLayout` you have arranged your views by giving reference to other views. It would be good to check this [link](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout) for a better understanding of how to use `ConstraintLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </WebView>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:onClick="gohome"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:onClick="clickexit"
        android:text="Chiudi"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textview"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#0000ff"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am not expert with the code. After upgrading Android Studio, I got a mess: so many errors to set. Now I have only warnings. But I have only 1 button, not 2 buttons any more as I had. This drives me crazy, because I am building only a webapp, and wanted to add few stuff to make my app nicer. And to had the other button I know I will go mad. Anyway, thank you for your help. I'll study the link you suggested.